"apt install emacs" linuxmint22 requires a mail system
This seems like it must be a terrible oversight: if you
sudo apt install emacs

in linuxmint 22, the package brings in a kitchen sink of email systems, which in turn requires system configuration (you have to tell it how to configure email for your system).
This has to be a mistake: emacs can do so much without a mail system.  In addition, I have my students install emacs right away when they learn linux, and this makes it very off-putting.
Does anyone know how to submit a problem report?  I tried using linuxmint's "element" channel, but I was unable to then find what happened to my question - it got lost in a sea.

This is unrelated to Emacs: it's a packaging problem with Mint (or maybe Ubuntu), so you should ask this question on a Mint (or maybe Ubuntu) forum.

This is due to a change in Ubuntu packaging for emacs-bin-common package (dependency of the emacs-nox package and in turn the emacs meta-package); specifically, the mailutils (meta-)package is now a recommended package rather than a suggested package on Ubuntu 24.04.
As apt installs recommended packages by default (due to the apt config option APT::Install-Recommends "true"; in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99synaptic), to install emacs without having to install mailutils, you can use --no-install-recommends with apt/apt-get for this time only:
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends emacs 

(I would not suggest disabling the installation of recommended packages globally through apt config file.)

Linux Mint 22 is based on Ubuntu 24.04 and uses upstream Ubuntu repositories for most packages -- emacs is also one of them.
On Ubuntu 24.04 (Mint 22), mailutils is a recommended package whereas on Ubuntu 22.04 (Mint 21.3), mailutils is a suggested package.. As suggested packages are not installed by default, mailutils is not installed when installing emacs on Mint 21.3 (Ubuntu 22.04).
FWIW, Ubuntu's upstream Debian has mailutils as recommended package even on Emacs 26 but Ubuntu kept the package as suggested until recently.

I think the mailutils was added as recommended by Debian starting from Emacs 26 due to the introduction of the --with-mailutils build option, from NEWS:

** The new option 'configure --with-mailutils' causes Emacs to rely on GNU Mailutils to retrieve email.  It is recommended, and is the
default if GNU Mailutils is installed.  When '--with-mailutils' is not
in effect, the Emacs build procedure by default continues to build and
install a limited 'movemail' substitute that retrieves POP3 email only
via insecure channels.  To avoid this problem, use either
'--with-mailutils' or '--without-pop' when configuring;
'--without-pop' is the default on platforms other than native
MS-Windows.

Presumably, the packaged binary from Debian was built using the --with-mailutils option and they followed the official recommendation to include mailutils package as a recommended package.
Now, Ubuntu kept the emacs-bin-common as suggested earlier mentioning the following in the changelog (excerpt from /usr/share/doc/emacs-bin-common/changelog.Debian.gz of version 1:27.1+1-3ubuntu1):


Merge from Debian unstable.  Remaining changes:

Demote mailutils Recommends to a Suggests, as it's in
universe, pulls in an MTA, and is nutty to require for a text editor.




Unfortunately, I can't find the exact Ubuntu release this decision (to demote upstream's decision and keep mailutils as suggested) was reverted and what was the reasoning behind it.

thank you for the complete research on it; I think it's an unfortunate choice, but thanks to your answer I have (a) a workaround [still sad to have to give someone new to linux such a messy command], and (b) the clarity that I should bring it up in debian

@markgalassi I've added some more info that might also be helpful in this context.

Ultimately it is a problem with their apt package, which they probably get from Ubuntu who may ultimately just use whatever package Debian created. You need to figure out who maintains that particular package and talk to them directly.
